# I can not really understand the difference between conjunctions and prepositions. What should I study for better grasp?

Tags: grammar

It is difficult for me to distinguish these two from each other in sentences, and it bothers me.
I did some research,d but that wasn't enough or complete.

Comment: Can you provide links to the explanations that you find confusing?

Comment: There are far fewer conjunctions than prepositions, so you could memorize this list, as well as try to understand the explanation: https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-conjunctions.html

Answer (score 2):

Conjunctions join two of the same type of thing together, like verb and verb, noun and noun, clause and clause, etc.

> run **or** walk
> My brother **and** I
> Talk to me **before** you go.

A preposition has a *complement*, nearly always a noun, and indicates a connection between this noun and the rest of the sentence.

> I love to walk **in** *the rain*.
> The weather today is cloudy **with** *a chance of rain*.
> The towel **on** *the bed* is wet.